# Positioning SKSpriteNode issue with iAd

Tags: swift, position, nodes, iad

So I'm having this pain in the *** issue with my scene setup.

All right, so I did what this guy suggested ([dealing with different screen sizes in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161987/dealing-with-different-screen-sizes-in-xcode)) with the scaling, so my scene looks identical regardless of iPhone screen size.

But! I'm having an issue.

At the top of my screen (portrait mode) I've an iAd banner view.

Just below that, I have my menu (which is an SKSpriteNode).

My problem is, that the iAd banner view does not scale, so I'm stuck here unable to position my menu so it will be shown 100% each time.

If it fits in the iPhone 6 Plus simulator, the top of it is hidden behind the iAd banner when I run the iPhone 6 simulator.

Is there anyway to add some sort of constrains programmatically so that my menu node will always be 0 points away from the iAd banner view on the y-axis.

I hope someone out there could point me in the right direction; maybe there's a smarter way of dealing with the different screen sizes?

Looking forward to hear from you.

Bests.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so - I came by my issue by hardcoding each objects position like this:

```
func setupUI() {

    if(self.size.height == 736) {
        print("iPhone 6 plus")
    }
    if(self.size.height == 667) {
        print("iPhone 6")
    }
    if(self.size.height == 568) {
        print("iPhone 5")
    }
    if(self.size.height == 480) {
        print("iPhone 4")
    }
}
```

I hope this helps out someone :-)